# Remove sidebar in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, margins

With the following code, I tried to remove the sidebar:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \frametitle{Test}
        I wrote some text, which should appear on the left.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sidebar prob]

I found that `\begin{frame}[plain]` is sufficient. However, I gives me:

[image: sidebar prob]

The sidebar isn't there, but the place is not used. How can I use it, i.e., move the `block` as if there were no sidebar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need the sidebar in the whole presentation, perhaps it worth to use

```
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0pt}
```

in the preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        I wrote some text, which should appear on the left.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

To have only one frame without sidebar, the previous solution does not work. So, you might want to do some manual work:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
}

%\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0pt}

\begin{document}
     \begin{frame}{First test}
        I wrote some very long text, which should appear on the left.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]{Test}
    \hspace*{-1.5cm}\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
        This is some text.
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item one
        \item two
        \end{itemize}
        I wrote some very long text, which should appear on the left.
    }    
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Another test}
        I wrote some very long text, which should appear on the left.
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the space as you like, but remember that in this way the right margin is shifted on the left.

Comment: There is also an option in the Hannover theme to set the sidebar width: `\usetheme[width=0pt]{Hannover}`

Comment: @jenson_bo: yes, that works too.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino What to do when I need to remove sidebar from only one (introductory) page?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: see my edit. I would never recommend to do this kind of stuff as all the text is shifted left of that given amount of space. BTW: if for introductory page you mean the first page, things are slightly different.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I mean title page, table of contents etc. thanks.